# What are my options to make a vanity cabinet the same depth as the deeper side cabinet?

Tags: bathroom, cabinets, vanity, custom-cabinetry

My bathroom originally had a custom cabinet and vanity set installed. I intended on reusing them in my bathroom remodel, but I found both of them had mold damage and disposed them during demo.

My plan was to raise the soffit above the cabinet in the picture to meet the rest of the ceiling but I found the drain vent pipe was concealed inside the soffit so I left that alone and decided to find something off the shelf to replicate the original setup. The height to the soffit was 82” and I was able to find an IKEA cabinet that would fit in that area.

The IKEA cabinet comes out 25” from the wall, but all the vanities I’ve found are only 19” or 22” deep. This leaves an unappealing gap between the cabinet and the vanity. I haven’t bought a vanity yet but the cabinet is installed and I’d rather not have to take it down and get something custom built. What are my options for having the vanity become flush with the cabinet? Is there any way to buy a 22” vanity and make it appear flush with the cabinet? Can a 25” deep vanity be custom made or would it be simpler to have a custom cabinet made?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is it important that they're flush? Where would this "gap" be? Cabinets jog in and out all the time. My own bathroom does exactly that.

Comment: @isherwood the wife wants the cabinet and the vanity to be flush. She didn’t think it would look good if it wasn’t flush. I’m going to show her the photos you shared because it actually isn’t very noticeable to me.

Comment: Cases in point: [1](https://russellcabinets.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/V22.jpg), [2](https://www.rdhenry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/bathroom-18.jpg), [3](https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2013/7/1/1/Original_Jamie-Gold-bathroom-toiletries-cabinet_s3x4.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.476.635.suffix/1400981900550.jpeg)

Comment: Point out that with flush cabinets your top will protrude awkwardly. That may be the primary reason the side cabinet is deeper in many cases.

Comment: @isherwood with the help of your pictures, the wife is ok with the vanity not being flush with the cabinet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wall mount that come out 3" or so your new vanity is flush with the 25" cabinet. You then hide the gap with some molding or backsplash